# How to find diagnostic setting(AuditEvent) for KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, powershell-az-module

I am able to find out the diagnostic setting for KeyVault - when I enable it individually by selecting the specified category - AuditEvent using the command  `Get-AzDiagnosticSetting`

But when I enable it by selecting **Category Groups** - audit & allLogs above command does not return any output.

Is there any alternative approach to check if AuditEvent logging is enabled for KeyVault?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Azure Management REST API [Diagnostic Settings-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnostic-settings/get) to get the active Diagnostic settings for the specified resource. I have tested this from my end it is working fine.

***Here is the sample screenshot for reference:***

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to derive the same information using AZ PowerShell Module?

Comment: @PrashantShete, you cannot pull the diagnostic settings which were created with category/groups using powershell cmdlets. Alternatively you can use [az monitor diagnostic-settings categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/diagnostic-settings/categories?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-diagnostic-settings-categories-show) show cmdlets to pull the diagnostic settings of the resource.